# Burned valve Ford Focus 1.6 16v (2010)

Tags: engine, ford, focus, valve, lpg

and thanks in advance for your help.
I have Ford Focus 1.6 16v 2010 model bought brand new.I"v had installed an LPG gas system "Lowato" from the beginning almost,and never had any problems with the car till the 100k kilometers.Than the car loss power and was diagnosed with burned exhaust valve.Although the repair wasn't cheap it solve the problem,and I had drive trough another 30k like nothing happened.Until it did again!
My mechanic replaced the valves,gasket and everything it should,and advice me to sip a (special) oil bcz that was the problem according to him.Fuel engine run too dry on the LPG alone,and that cause it the burned valves.So after another 25k running it with a mixture like a "dirt bike" :) it break down jet again, and with the completely the same issue :( cant believed myself
My mechanic continue to blame the replacement valves,although they were original ,and I am just sick from excuses and throwing money away.
Anyone who had some insight or can point to the possible cause of this problems will be greatly appreciated.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It seems to me you should just go back to petrol and call it a day. I don't think you're going to have any different results running LPG in the car. It seems like it may be running a tad lean, which would increase the exhaust temperatures and thus possibly burning the valves. It's either that or you need to take it to a different mechanic. After three sets of exhaust valves, I'm surprised the seats aren't toast and you just need a completely new head.

Comment: LPG system is set too lean, have a qualified LPG technician look at it. This should not happen with a quality installation of LPG.